# Ubuntu 16.04 "Toggle Shaded Mode" Keyboard command bug Ctrl+Alt+S

Tags: shortcut-keys, gui, window, bug-reporting

- I am pretty new to this whole Linux thing, but I have to say I love it far more than Windows 10.
- I am a new user to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial and I love it.

However, I recently tried a keyboard command called "Toggle Shaded State." The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, and after pressing it without any knowledge, I found that my <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> keyboard shortcut is messed up.

When ever you <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> your windows should switch giving you the free flow of working between them, but now all it does is bring up a window I want to switch to and leave my current window as the active one. For example if I am in the Google Chrome browser and want to switch to my terminal by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, then instead it leaves me in Google Chrome browser and only pulls up my terminal and leaves in an inactive shaded mode.

I have tried disabling the shortcut, restarting, shutting down, rebooting, and even restarting the GUI with online help, but nothing seems to correct the issue. I have tried restarting the GUI with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and resetting `lightdm` with `sudo` access.

I have also tried the replace command `unity --replace`, but nothing seems to correct the issue I am having.

After doing some research, I found that this keyboard command bugs Ubuntu 16.04 which is my current distro.

I hope I can get some support back pretty soon as I have found this bug to be a huge inconvenience and it crashed my System Settings menu and would not allow me to reopen the application to change the options of my computer until I rebooted the system.

Comment: Why did you tag this with "unsupported packages"?

Comment: I apologize, I just wanted to make sure it was read and didn't pay attention to that ridiculous tag.

Comment: In that case, I'll remove that tag. P.S. You can see in the upper right that you question has been viewed 7 times.